# Excel vba open read only file error

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have a vba macro to open Excel files, including Read-only files.

I use the following code to do this:

```
Workbooks.Open((FileName:=MyFileName, UpdateLinks:=0, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
```

Up until June 2013 this never failed. As of now this no longer works. Now when the macro encounters a read-only file the file appears in a separate window and a Save As prompt also appears (never happened before).

If I click Cancel I get a Path not found error. If I click Save the file gets saved to its original location. This is completely new. There is no Save As command in this part of my code.

It appears to be something new associated with Microsoft’s File > Protect Workbook > Mark as final stuff. Anyone seeing this? I can’t find a way to prevent it. I simply want to be able to open the read only file without further prompts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suppress "File In Use" Dialogue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32251001/suppress-file-in-use-dialogue). Recommend you add the `ReadOnly:=True` and `Notify:=False` parameters to the [Workbooks.Open method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195811(v=office.11).aspx) command.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used VBA with excel much, but is it possible that the macro security settings within excel were reset so that it no longer trusts macros or VBA script attempting to use it.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, however, this should not be posted as an answer, but rather as a comment to the original question.

Comment: I wish I could, unfortunately I do not have enough points since I recently joined. I am currently trying to get those points so that I can do comments instead of answers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input. I did find a work-around. In newer versions of Excel there is a new ReadOnly designation: Final, i.e. File > Protect workbook > Mark as Final. This is the same as ReadOnly, just by another name, and it does not show up as an option in WorkBooks.Open(FileName:= ...). If I set the Workbook.Final property = False, then I can open the file w/o the SaveAs prompt.

If wbName.Final = True Then
 wbName.Final = False
End If